# Seeking Advice on Normalizing Implied Volatility Change for Options Modeling

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility, probability, volatility-surface, joint-probability

I'm working with a substantial dataset spanning five years of weekly options data, with records down to the second. My goal is to develop a model that can accurately predict the probability mass function (PMF) of the BSM ATM implied volatility(IV) reaction in **1 day** if current IV, current time to expiration(DTE), and percentage change in underlying are given.

**Here's where I'm seeking advice:**
Implied volatility changes vary significantly with DTE, with options nearing expiry showing larger changes compared to those further out.

To address this issue, I'm looking to derive the **normalized implied volatility change value** for various expiries relative to the percentage change in the underlying asset over 1 day.

After normalizing the implied volatility change, I'll use kernel density estimation (KDE) to build its distribution.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, best practices, or recommendations from experienced practitioners in the field regarding the normalization process.

Thank you all for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I did abit of research on normalizing IV, where I used the cross-sectional average of IV among option IVs (with different strike prices). You may also use a time-series average of IVs - like the IV of that option for the past 1 month. Both of these averages can be used to scale/normalize your IV values.

I am not sure if this is the industry way, but there are academics that have used both of these methods that I mentioned above.